# My drop down doesn't work when I click on the second time on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, use-state

I need my drop-down button to show the text below if I press one, and another one for hiding. I tried to use the useState method, but it also doesn't work, and same with the non-useState method. Here is my code, hope someone can fix this, thanks

```
    function AnnouncementCard(props) {
      const { announcement } = props;
    
      const triangleDown = <img src={DropDown} alt="No-img" />;
      const triangleUp = <img src={DropDownActive} alt="No-img" />;
    
      function Readmore() {
        console.log("inject", currentTriangle);
        if (currentTriangle == triangleDown) {
          DisplayText(null);
          ChangeTriangle(triangleUp);
          console.log(2, currentTriangle);
        } else if (currentTriangle == triangleUp) {
          DisplayText(<Text>{announcement.detail}</Text>);
          ChangeTriangle(triangleDown);
          console.log(1, currentTriangle);
        }
      }
    
      const [currentTriangle, ChangeTriangle] = useState(triangleUp);
      const [currentText, DisplayText] = useState(null);
    
      return (
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <PictureBox>
              <Picture src={announcement.img} alt="no-img" />
            </PictureBox>
            <TextBox>
              <Title>{announcement.title}</Title>
              <Date>{announcement.date}</Date>
              <ReadMore onClick={() => {Readmore();}}>
                Read more
                <Triangle>{currentTriangle}</Triangle>
              </ReadMore>
            </TextBox>
          </CardBody>
          <Textarea>{currentText}</Textarea>
        </Card>
      );
    }
    
    export default AnnouncementCard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply compare JSX elements using `==` operator (`currentTriangle == triangleDown`). To make it simple, I would use a boolean instead of saving the element in the state, and depending on that you can show up and down buttons.

1. Replace the `ChangeTriangle` state hook with the following.

```
const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(true);
```

2. Update the `ReadMore` function as below.

```
  function Readmore() {
    if (toggleValue === false) {
      DisplayText(null);
      setToggleValue(true);
    } else if (toggleValue === true) {
      DisplayText(<Text>{announcement.detail}</Text>);
      setToggleValue(false);
    }
  }
```

3. Set the triangle button as below using a ternary operator.

```
<Triangle>{toggleValue ? triangleUp : triangleDown}</Triangle>
```

Comment: @テンカサン, check this out !!

Comment: let me know if you still have any issues?